# ¿Cómo puedo borrar el cache del navegador por medio de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, cache, internet-explorer

Es posible borrar el cache del navegador(IE 11) por medio de una función de JavaScript.

Comment: No, eso sería una brecha de seguridad enorme el que JavaScript tuviera acceso a la caché del navegador. A lo más que puedes aspirar es por medio de cabeceras no permitir cachear tus datos, así como quitar el autocompletar de los formularios y así.

Answer (score 2):

No sé si exista esa opción en *javascript*, pero lo que podría servirte es recargar la página desde el servidor:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

El parámetro `forceReload` del método [`reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) indica que no se utilice el cache.

Comment: No en todas las ocasiones el reload fuerza el servidor (o las CDN o proxy) a devolver nuevo contenido. Una estrategia que si invalida caché (y también fecha de expirado del contenido) es volver a cargar la url añadiendo un parámetro extra randomico. Por ejemplo `&force=XXX`. Donde XXX puede ser un Math.random